# Resources images subfolder problem for ios .net maui

Tags: maui

below the image with source having subfolder in the image folder of the .net maui, i am not able to get the image in iOS.

```xml
<ImageButton Command="{Binding Path=GotoPreviousCommand}"
             Source="info_icons/next_left.svg"/>
<ImageButton Command="{Binding Path=GotoNextCommand}"
             Source="info_icons/next_right.svg"/>
```

Comment: You could just tried ```Source="next_left.png"```.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> .NET MAUI converts SVG files to PNG files. Therefore, when adding an SVG file to your .NET MAUI app project, it should be referenced from XAML or C# with a .png extension.

Although you add a subfolder, you could just reference the image in this way (no need to add subfolder):

```xml
<ImageButton Command="{Binding Path=GotoPreviousCommand}"
             Source="next_left.png"/>
```

For more info, you could refer to [load local image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/image#load-a-local-image).

Hope it helps!

Comment: For anyone reading this: In Android this works `<Image Source="subfolder/image.png" />` but on iOS the paths are flattened for some reason `subfolder/image.png` doesn't work but `image.png` does.